# Search for arbitrary files but only list matches in results once

Tags: find, locate, file-search

I want to search for arbitrary file/directory names, but only want to list file paths containing the search string at the same position once.
Especially not every file within a directory matching the search string.

Here is an example, `locate -i flatpak` lists:

```
/etc/flatpak
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.Flatpak.SystemHelper.conf
/etc/flatpak/remotes.d
/etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak/installation-tmp/repo/objects/74
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak/installation-tmp/repo/objects/75
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak/installation-tmp/repo/objects/76
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak/installation-tmp/repo/objects/77
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak/installation-tmp/repo/objects/78
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak/installation-tmp/repo/objects/79
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak/installation-tmp/repo/objects/7a
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak/installation-tmp/repo/objects/7b
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak/installation-tmp/repo/objects/7c
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak/installation-tmp/repo/objects/7d
/var/lib/flatpak
/var/lib/flatpak/.changed
/var/lib/flatpak/.removed
/var/lib/flatpak/app
/var/lib/flatpak/appstream
/var/lib/flatpak/exports
/var/lib/flatpak/repo
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime
```

But I want a search result like this:

```
/etc/flatpak
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.Flatpak.SystemHelper.conf
/etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh
/home/simon/.cache/gnome-software/flatpak
/var/lib/flatpak
```

And which tool is best suited for this? `locate`, `find`, `fd-find`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to search for `flatpak` in the file name only (and not in other path components), so you can use the `-b`/`--basename` option:

So:

```
locate -ib flatpak
```

Another approach could be to use the `-r`/`--regex` option and write:

```
locate -ir 'flapak[^/]*$'
```

That is `flatpak` followed by any number of characters other than `/` followed by the end of the file path.

That might however miss filenames that have non-characters (in the current locale) after `flatpak`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` to remove everything after the pattern `flatpak`, then you can sort the output and only print unique lines:

```
locate -i flatpak | sed -E -e 's/(flatpak\/?).*/\1/i' -e 's/\/$//' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: This is a nice start, but it will mess up `/etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh` and doesn’t account for case-insensitive matches.

Comment: Cheers, added `i` to the `sed`  substitution

Comment: oh yeah this will mess up `flatpak.sh`, I'll update shortly

Comment: I think `sed -E -e 's/(flatpak[^/]*).*/\1/i'` should do the trick; it doesn’t even need the second expression.

Answer (score 2):

To use `find` to look through the whole file system for filenames containing the string `flatpack` in their names:

```
find / -name '*flatpack*'
```

If your `find` implementation has `-iname`, then you may use that in place of `-name` to search case insensitively.  If you want to search for only regular files, then also use `-type f` (your example involves finding *any* type of file, so you should probably leave this out):

```
find / -type f -iname '*flatpack*'
```

This would likely give you a number of "permission denied" errors as `find` tries to descend into directories that you don't have access to.  To avoid that, you could potentially use GNU `find` like so:

```
find / ! -readable -prune -o -iname '*flatpack*' -print
```

This would be slower than using `locate -ib flatpack`, but would always give you up-to-date results. The data that `locate` is using is gathered on a daily or weekly basis, and will not include paths that are not readable by all users.